# Jena Fuseki assembler file + TDB + OWL reasoner

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, owl, fuseki

I am having a problem configuring Jena Fuseki using an assembler file. Up until recently I had been starting the server from the command line as follows:

```
sudo ./fuseki-server --loc=la --port=3032 --update /ds
```

This creates a persistent TDB store located in the directory SERVER_ROOT/la. The server starts correctly and displays the following output:

```
14:30:55 INFO  TDB dataset: directory=la
14:30:55 INFO  Dataset path = /ds
14:30:55 INFO  Fuseki 1.0.1 2014-01-18T19:01:20+0000
14:30:55 INFO  Started 2015/02/02 14:30:55 GMT on port 3032
```

Now I want to add in an OWL reasoner and following [baach.de's article](https://baach.de/Members/jhb/getting-started-with-jena-fuseki-and-owl-reasoning), I have been trying to run the server with the following assembler file:

```
@prefix : <#> .
@prefix fuseki: <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix tdb: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix ja: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
@prefix sdb: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2007/sdb#> .

[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;

fuseki:services ( <#tdb> ) .

<#tdb> rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
    fuseki:name "ds" ; # http://host/inf
    fuseki:serviceQuery "sparql" ; # SPARQL query service
    #fuseki:serviceUpdate     "update" ;
    fuseki:dataset <#dataset2> ; #select which set to use
    .

[] ja:loadClass "com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB" .

tdb:DatasetTDB rdfs:subClassOf ja:RDFDataset .
tdb:GraphTDB rdfs:subClassOf ja:Model .

<#dataset2> rdf:type ja:RDFDataset ;
    ja:defaultGraph <#model2> .

<#model2> a ja:InfModel ;
    ja:baseModel <#tdbGraph> ;
    ja:reasoner [ ja:reasonerURL <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2003/OWLFBRuleReasoner>] .

<#tdbDataset> rdf:type tdb:DatasetTDB ;
    tdb:location "la" ;
    tdb:unionDefaultGraph true .

<#tdbGraph> rdf:type tdb:GraphTDB ;
    tdb:dataset <#tdbDataset> .
```

Using this command:

```
sudo ./fuseki-server --port=3032 --config=fuseki-la-cfg.ttl
```

The server starts correctly displaying the following output:

```
14:29:52 INFO  Dataset path = /ds
14:29:52 INFO  Fuseki 1.0.1 2014-01-18T19:01:20+0000
14:29:52 INFO  Started 2015/02/02 14:29:52 GMT on port 3032
```

Notice however, how it no longer prints the 'TDB dataset: directory=la' status. When I query the server using the built-in Fuseki HTML interface, the server hangs after it receives the query and does not return a result.

Can anyone point out to me what is wrong with my assembler file? Am I selecting the 'la' directory correctly to act as my TDB store's location?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: "TDB dataset: directory=" is printed when the command line has "--loc". It's not printed for an assembler.

Comment: How big is the dataset? You are running a reasoner over a persistent store. That can be simply very slow.

Comment: It's got a million triples in it. That's not that big, is it?

Comment: Yes @AndyS that was the problem. I tried a dataset with a couple of triples and it worked fine. So does this mean that an OWL reasoner will only work for very small persistent TDBs? If so, it's fairly useless then. Or in general is it better to run big datasets in memory?

Comment: A million isn't big but combing query and the forward-backward reasoner can have unfavourable access patterns when used with a database.  Do you need all the features of the OWLFBRuleReasoner reasoner? Less ones go faster.  And you might expand the data once and load that so as not to need the reasoner at runtime.

Comment: @AndyS I like the expand and load idea. I'll give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: @AndyS could you help please if you have some time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067247/fuseki-reasoner-not-working-with-tdb