# fuseki config to an in memory with reasoner not working

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, fuseki

These settings were working with fuseki 2.0, now i am on fuseki 2.3, but these settings not working any more:

```
[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;
    fuseki:services (
        <#serviceInMemoryWithReasoner>
    )
.



<#serviceInMemoryWithReasoner> rdf:type fuseki:Service;
    rdfs:label "testdataset";
    fuseki:name "testdataset";
    fuseki:serviceQuery "query";
    fuseki:serviceUpdate "update";
    fuseki:dataset <#datasetServiceInMemoryWithReasoner> ;
.

<#datasetServiceInMemoryWithReasoner> rdf:type ja:RDFDataset;
    ja:defaultGraph <#datasetmodelServiceInMemoryWithReasoner>
.

<#datasetmodelServiceInMemoryWithReasoner>
    ja:reasoner [ ja:reasonerURL <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2003/OWLFBRuleReasoner>];
    ja:content [ja:externalContent <file:ProposalData/1.ttl> ];
.
```

This is the error I am having:

```
2016-03-21 12:31:12] WebAppContext WARN  Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4275c20c{/,file:///usr/local/apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.1/webapp/,STARTING}
org.apache.jena.fuseki.FusekiConfigException
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiConfig.readConfiguration(FusekiConfig.java:244)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiConfig.readConfigurationDirectory(FusekiConfig.java:223)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServer.initializeDataAccessPoints(FusekiServer.java:212)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServerListener.init(FusekiServerListener.java:78)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServerListener.contextInitialized(FusekiServerListener.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.jetty.JettyFuseki.start(JettyFuseki.java:120)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.exec(FusekiCmd.java:359)
    at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainMethod(CmdMain.java:93)
    at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:58)
    at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:45)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.innerMain(FusekiCmd.java:95)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd.main(FusekiCmd.java:60)
```

I can give you any other info you want, could you check please why my settings not working. i want to have a dataset in memory, that loads its tribles from a file

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I could find with this config was how the file is referenced (should be `file://`). Below is a complete config, including prefixes, which works in Fuseki 2.5.0. I placed the test data and the ontology in separate files for clarity.

```
@prefix tdb:   <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix ja:    <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix fuseki: <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .

[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;
    fuseki:services (
        <#serviceInMemoryWithReasoner>
    )
.

<#serviceInMemoryWithReasoner> rdf:type fuseki:Service;
    rdfs:label  "testdataset";
    fuseki:name "testdataset";
    fuseki:serviceQuery "query";
    fuseki:serviceUpdate "update";
    fuseki:dataset <#datasetServiceInMemoryWithReasoner> ;
.

<#datasetServiceInMemoryWithReasoner> rdf:type ja:RDFDataset;
    ja:defaultGraph <#datasetmodelServiceInMemoryWithReasoner>
.

<#datasetmodelServiceInMemoryWithReasoner>
    ja:reasoner [ ja:reasonerURL <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2003/OWLFBRuleReasoner>];
    ja:content  [ja:externalContent <file://my/data/dir/data.ttl> ];
    ja:content  [ja:externalContent <file://my/data/dir/model.ttl> ];
```