# expand tdb triple store using reasoner

Tags: rdf, jena, fuseki, reasoning, tdb

I have a Fuseki database with 1.5 million triples, stored in a persistant tdb store. Simple queries without reasoning work very well, but when using the Owl forward-backward reasoner provided with Fuseki the performance drops dramatically, leading to very long response times and Java memory errors.

In a related question ([Jena Fuseki assembler file + TDB + OWL reasoner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278420/jena-fuseki-assembler-file-tdb-owl-reasoner)) it was suggested by @andys to expand the triples once using the reasoner, store the expanded triples and query without the reasoner. This solution has some obvious conceptual and practical disadvantages but I would like to try it. So the question is: how can I do this?

The most important example would be transitive closure. Given

```
:myCat rdf:type :cat
:cat rdf:type :animal
```

Add to the triple store:

```
:myCat rdf:type :animal
```

Comment: `:cat rdfs:subClassOf :animal .` to get that inference. (You do not need the OWL reasoner for this, other reasoners wil do it with less overhead.)

Comment: The infernce engines run in-memory so write run once, writing out the the whole graph, inferences and base data, and load that.

Comment: @AndyS can you expand on how to do that exactly, with a query, with one of the command-line tools provided with Jena/Fuseki, or from within Java?